# Error con List Flutter RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: api, flutter, rest, dart

Estoy realizando una petición http, pero como tengo 2 botones, uno el cual escaneo un codigo qr y otro donde hago una consulta con el resultado scaneado donde mi codigo de consulta es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En dado caso que sea null o no se tenga en base de datos he puesto la siguiente validación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en especial me marca error en donde hago `this.resultadoBD[0]["sociedad"] == null`
porque me dice que no es valor valido `RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0`

Comment: Significa que `userList` esta vacio.

Comment: podrías hacer un print de la lista de usuarios, para ver que retorna y edita tu respuesta poniendo esa parte

Comment: Si esta vació como puedo validar para que ponga un espacio en blanco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que resultadoBD es vacío, por eso te lanza la excepción al momento de validar.

También tienes otra validación incorrecta, `this.resultadoBD.length <0`, el tamaño nunca será menor que 0.

Podrías hacer la validación de esta manera:

```dart
subtitulo: this.resultadoBD.isEmpty? '' : this.resultadoBD.first["sociedad"]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, no sabia sobre asignarle en .first que pudiera solventar el error

Comment: En realidad el problema fue la validación, primero te aseguras de que si tu lista es vacía, entonces muestras vacío, sino recien accedes al primer elemento. pudo ser  resultadoBD.first o resultadoBD[0] , igual funcionará.